# issue when fire up spark: "env: jupyter: Not a directory"

Tags: apache-spark, installation, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to spark. So my first step is to install the Spark. I followed steps from this link:

http://genomegeek.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-install-apache-spark-on-mac-os-x.html

when I finished all the steps and try to fire up the spark, Scala seems fine to me, but python is not, and I got this:

```
$ ./bin/pyspark
$ env: jupyter: Not a directory
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a time of investigation, I find out it is due to lack of jupyter notebook.